# Draw continous line on Georeferenced image and obtain GPS coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, navigation, gps, gdal

I need to draw a Path on a Geo-referenced or normal image or a Map and get the **GPS coordinates** of the way. These way points will be used for navigation. I was able to do this using JavaScript - Google Maps API using Poly-line feature, but its not a good solution as its not free anymore.

So I'm thinking of  using a drone and taking a Geo-referenced aerial picture, but i need a tool which can give me the coordinate list of the drawn path. I've come across **GDAL**, and other methods but I'm kinda lost and confused what to use and how to implement it.

Would be really helpful if anyone can guide me how this can be done efficiently.

[I need something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eJze.jpg)

Comment: Have you coded something?

Comment: @MichaelMontero For this application? Yes, using Google maps API in Javascript, which will return all the lat,long points when i draw poly lines on the map. But I'm thinking of other possibilities now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet is open and can use open map tiles free for use. There is vector layer tools available. See the docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html

Specifically polylines: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#polyline